# shy: tímido vs. reservado vs. vergonzoso vs. penoso

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, adjetivos, vocabulario

In many parts of the Spanish-speaking world, describing a person who is "shy" can be done with at least four different words:

- tímido
- reservado
- vergonzoso
- penoso

What is the difference between these words, and what exactly does each one refer to? Which is the most general translation of "shy"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many meanings with these words:

- *Tímido* and *vergonzoso*: their main difference could be that with *vergonzoso* you emphasize the fact the person you're talking about feels (or could feel) shame when doing something. With *tímido* you only say he/she will be more reluctant to behave in a more "direct" way, someone without "personality".
- *Reservado*: is someone who doesn't talk too much. A bit silent. A person who only speaks when he feels he has to.
- *Penoso*: According to [RAE's definition](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=penoso), in Cuba, El Salvador and México it means *Tímido* (I've just learned this today). Here in Chile, on the other hand, it means someone who makes the other people feel sorry for him, in a very bad way.

Comment: +1 "Penoso" means something completely different from "shy" also here (Argentina).

Comment: "Penoso" in Spain is more like awful for a person or a situation and labourious or difficult for a task or a job (and this meaning is kind of out of use)

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the Miami Cubans that penoso meant shy. Have I been misinformed? Am I going around telling Spanish people that I am messed up?

Comment: _Penoso_ derives from _pena_, which has different meanings, some of them depending on the country. [_Pena_](https://dle.rae.es/pena): sadness, punishment, pain, difficulty, shyness,... [_Penoso_](https://dle.rae.es/penoso): arduous, pitiful, afflicted, unfortunate, flamboyant, shy. The last two meanings are contradictory! Take a look at the links,